# How to access the local path of a downloaded image Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

here is how i am downloading Images.Now i had create one more pipline to insert my scraped data.

```
class CmindexPipeline(ImagesPipeline):



    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):

        for image_url in item['image_url']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        item['image_paths'] = image_paths
        print("From Images Items", item)
        return item



class MysqlPipline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        print("From Process Items",item['image_path'])
```

here is my settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'cmindex.pipelines.CmindexPipeline': 1,'cmindex.pipelines.MysqlPipline':2}
IMAGES_STORE ='E:\WorkPlace\python\cmindex\cmindex\img'
IMAGES_THUMBS = {
    '16X16': (16, 16)
}
```

But unfortunately sill i am not able to access item['image_paths'] in process_item.it raise error

```
KeyError: 'image_paths'
```

If anyone know what i am doing wrong please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `process_item` method is called before `item_completed`, so it does not have the `image_paths` yet.

If you want to access the `image_paths`, you will have to do it inside `item_completed`, or write another pipeline that is placed after the image pipeline.

Comment: Thanks I had created another pipeline then i was able to access images path in item.